# Form select type: setting default based on options' value

Tags: forms

So I've got this form:

```
$form['color'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Kleur'),
        '#options' => array(
            0 => t('Wit'),
            1 => t('Geel'),
            2 => t('Groen'),
            3 => t('Rood'),
        ),
        '#default_value' => 'Rood',
  );
```

As expected, this doesn't currently set the default value to 'Rood'. How would I get it so that the default value can be accessed by it's value?

Note that this example shows the string 'Rood', but in practice it would be a variable string that is pulled from the database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Default value should point to key, not a value.

In your example, default_value should be as in below.

```
'#default_value' => 3,
```

Hope below link will help you.

https://www.drupal.org/node/240783#comment-1794710

Comment: Like I said, my default value comes from a database which holds the string values, so your solution won't help at all.

Comment: @Neglexis Just use `array_search` to determine the key from the value, Drupal won't have anything to help as it's just a basic language feature

Comment: @Clive, I tried array_search before, but it didn't work because my #options array doesn't seem to be fully defined when #default value is called. However, you did make me to rethink it, and defining an options array before the form seems to be the way to go :) Thanks!

Comment: Yep that's the one @Neglexis :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably use for loop to do this.
Like:

```
// options is a array variable contains the data as 
// options[0] = "Wit"
// options[1] = "Geel"
// options[2] = "Groen"
// options[3] = "Rood"

$string = ""; // $string will come from database that you want to be default.
for($i = 0; $i < strlen(options); $i++){
  if(options[$i] == $string){
    $catch_key = $i;
  }
}
```

and then at form field creation time

```
'#default_value' => $catch_key,
```

Comment: Right idea, wrong implementation - `array_search()` will be quicker

Comment: array_search() sometimes not work with the values which are not in utf-8.It might be provide the wrong result with the data like Ê, Â etc

Comment: So use UTF-8 encoding :)